# Google scripts run for trashed documents

Tags: google-apps-script

I've deleted spreadsheets with scripts attributed to them that run on a timed frequency. I also had notifications setup to inform me when a script had an error.

Since delete them I've gotten a steady stream of failure notifications that I can't stop, any ideas?

Comment: Reported in [Issue 143](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=143). Star it to receive updates.

Answer (score 1):

Did you empty the trash in Google Drive/Docs? That usually does the trick...