# Find a Google Apps Script to terminate it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I was trying Google script. I just copy a code from a example to create Google docs using Google script and I forgot to delete that script. Now problem is script is sending me a lots of emails and creating docs on my account. I am not able to find out the script to delete it for me.

Answer (score 2):

See [Issue 4096](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4096), requesting a "Means to manage and search over standalone and container-bound scripts". Without support from Google to enable searching within container-bound scripts, you must resort to seeking out your mystery function document-by-document.

---

The script must have a time-based trigger, if it's behaving that way. You may find help in one of these similar questions:

- [deleted script keeps running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180981/deleted-script-keeps-running)
- [How to delete a google apps script service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459410/how-to-delete-a-google-apps-script-service)
- [Google scripts run for trashed documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288499/google-scripts-run-for-trashed-documents)

#### Option 1 - disable the trigger function

From the Script Editor, you can disable any trigger on any script.

- Go to https://script.google.com/, which will open the script editor. You can just close the opening splash screen, without selecting a script type.
- Select "Resources - All your triggers...". You will be prompted to save this new script file - do that and continue.
- A dialog will open showing all your triggers. In your case, there should be just the one from the sample you were trying.
- Click the little <kbd>x</kbd> next to the trigger that's causing you grief, and it will be disabled.
- Exit, and delete the script file that was created in this exercise.

#### Option 2 - find script file & disable it

Since you recently created the script, the file it's in will be near the top of your document list, if sorted by date with most recent first.

In the Google Drive UI, select "More - All items" on the left-side navigation list. This will display all your documents. Now click the "LAST MODIFIED" column header so that the most recent documents are at the top. One of those contains your script.

Open that script file, disable the trigger function (similar to Option 1, but use "This script's triggers..."), then exit.

#### Option 2.1

You can see all scripts you've authorized listed in the "security" section of "My Account". [Link](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions)

This *may* be a shorter list than you see on your Google Drive, as it will only include scripts. Note though, that what is listed is the name of the script project, not the container document. (That's a good reason to name your script projects the same as the document.)

By clicking on a listed app, you can see details including the authorization date, which may help you narrow your search.

[image: screenshot]

With the name of an authorized script, let's assume that you've been been able to identify a few possible container documents. You now need to open those documents in Google Drive, open the Script Editor to determine if you've found the culprit, and then manually disable the trigger.

#### Warning

Be careful about deleting script files that have active triggers in them - others have had problems with that in past. For some, emptying the trash in Google Drive did not stop scripts from triggering.