# Find the Google Sheet or Script a trigger is in

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a trigger in Google Sheets/Scripts and made it run every day. Now I need to alter it and can't find the sheet/script that I put it in. All I have is the name of the trigger, but searching for that in google drive doesn't come up with anything. Solutions?

Comment: you may look at statistics of recently changed sheets and may be find it there

Comment: Possible duplicate: [script.google.com Project Not found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18012446/1677912).

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is a duplicate. Thank you (I did search what I thought was pretty extensively :)).

Comment: Such a n00b I apparently can't figure out what to do if my question is a duplicate. My google skills (just spent 15 mins looking) apparently are the root of this question ;)